# How to create an alias for the part of SQL query without SELECTing it

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to create an alias for the part of SQL query without `SELECT`ing it?

For example, if I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    product_name,
    SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) LIKE '%live%')  AS count_live,
    SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) LIKE '%demo%')  AS count_demo,
    SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) NOT LIKE '%live%' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) NOT LIKE '%demo%') AS count_other,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM `foo` GROUP BY product_name
;
```

can I create an alias for the `SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1)` to reduce the code duplication?

Comment: you can set it and use it later. like set @rep:= SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) and use it like SUM(SELECT [at the rate]rep LIKE '%live%') ---> I did not tested it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't alias part of a SELECT, you could write a function that does exactly `SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '|', -1)` but this would only get you as far as `MY_FUNCTION(field)`.

You could also do the substring bit first in a subquery and then wrap it in a further select:

```
  SELECT product_name,
         SUM(status LIKE '%live%') AS count_live,
         SUM(status LIKE '%demo%') AS count_demo,
         SUM(status NOT LIKE '%live%' AND status NOT LIKE '%demo%') AS count_other,
         COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM ( 
      SELECT product_name,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', -1) status,
        FROM foo
         ) s
GROUP BY product_name
```

I'd be worried this might use a lot of memory building the subquery results first and hamper performance. It's also still quite complicated.

Or you could split out the 'live/demo' from the `company_name` field in your table structure as mentioned on your previous question. ;)

Comment: Aka a derived table. Very convenient!

Comment: What's the use of this `s` after the inner `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Oh, that's a table alias, could be written `AS s`, all derived tables require them in MySQL. I could then have referenced the fields as s.product_name, s.status but as there is only one table these fields could come from (`s`) I omitted them.

Comment: So I can omit the `AS` keyword in MySQL?

Comment: Yes you can omit the `AS` keyword :)